# Not sure how to implement accessible enum in header file?

Tags: c++, enums

In a header file I have something basically like this

```
#ifndef blah
#define blah

enum DataType
{
    TextData,
    IntData

};


#endif
```

And in another file I have

```
#include "previousheaderdefinedabove"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::cout << DataType::TextData;


    return 1;
}
```

However, when I try to compile I get

```
main.cpp:13:18: error: expected a class or namespace
    std::cout << DataType::TextData;
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong, any help is much appreciated! I've seen enums being used as classes but is there a reason why the namespcae isn't enough?

Comment: Enum values are not scoped under the enum. The enum values are in the same scope as the enum definition.

Comment: To expand on what Dark Falcon has said, `std::cout << TextData;` will compile.

Comment: Use [`enum class`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum) if you want this kind of behaviour and your compiler supports C++11 features.

Comment: For this kind of usage, you could leave the word "DataType" out entirely, and use an anonymous enum if you wanted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The enum is neither a namespace nor a class; its values are in the same scope as the definition. In the above example, the enum values are in the global namespace.

That means, in main, you should have

```
std::cout << TextData;
```

instead of

```
std::cout << DataType::TextData;
```